# Returning Just count of records found in MYSQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, subquery

I have the following MYSQL query which returns the number of photos found for each record where the number of photos is greater than 0.

```
SELECT advert_id, (SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM advert_images b WHERE b.advert_id = adverts.advert_id) AS num_photos
FROM adverts
WHERE adverts.approve =  '1'
HAVING num_photos > 0
```

The query works fine, but I want to just return a count of the records found.  i.e. the number of records which have at least one photo.  I've tried to wrap the whole query in a COUNT, but it gives an error.  I want to do this in the query, and not a separate count of records found in php.

Comment: You can't use `HAVING` without a `GROUP BY` first.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalRecords 
FROM 
(
  SELECT a.advert_id, COUNT(*) AS num_photos
  FROM adverts AS a
    JOIN advert_images AS i
    ON i.advert_id = a.advert_id
  WHERE a.approve =  '1'
  GROUP BY a.advert_id
  HAVING num_photos > 0
) AS mq
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but that doesn't answer my question, it returns the ids and number of photos, but all I want it to return is the total number of records found that match the query.

Comment: ***@user1052096***, I updated my answer, is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT advert_id, (SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM advert_images b WHERE b.advert_id = adverts.advert_id) AS num_photos
FROM adverts
WHERE adverts.approve =  '1'
HAVING num_photos > 0) AS c
```

This should do the trick